# How to check if specific (not all) jQuery AJAX requests are finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following function which does some checks via ajax and enables/disables an add to cart button:

```
function formUpdate() {

    var data = {
        'action': 'my_action_name',
        'qty': $( '#qty' ).val(),
    };

    var request = jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'myajax.php',
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        async: true
    });

    request.done( function( response ) {

        // I disable my add to cart button here
        // Some code that takes a while to run to determine if add to cart should be enabled
        // I conditionally enable the add to cart here based on the above

    }

}

$( '#qty' ).on( 'change', function() {

    formUpdate();

});
```

The request is triggered when `#qty` (number) field is changed, when a user presses the up/down arrows on the field or uses the up/down keys the ajax request is sent multiple times and because the code in the `request.done` takes a while if the requests near the end result in a disabled add to cart button there is a brief period where the previous requests keep it enabled until the later requests are done - so a user could add to cart in that brief moment.

I want to eliminate this from occurring, I know I can use `async: false`, but this stops the user from using up/down arrows/keys until the request is done.

What I'd like to do is keep `async: true`, but ensure the add to cart remains disabled until all requests are completed - I have tried disabling the add to cart before the ajax request in the formUpdate function but this doesn't appear to work, assumed because of all the ajax requests enabling/disabling the add to cart button.

I am wondering if there is a way I can use the action name I am passing in data for the ajax request, then have a function that disables the add to cart button until all of the ajax requests with that name are finished running.

I have looked around for code for this but most of what I have found is related to ALL ajax requests, not specific ones.

Is this possible or is there another solution?

Comment: Instead of dealing with multiple ajax requests you can use a timeout to wait a bit after the user interaction before making the request.

Comment: @ChrisG could you provide an example of how I should do this, would that be in the #qty change function? I am a bit confused with timeouts and how they relate to the running order of the functions, if I set a time out on the qty change would that effectively queue the ajax requests one by one? I assumed this would cause the same result as setting async: false (stopping the user clicking/keying repeatedly on the qty field)? The part of this that confuses me is the "wait a bit" - I'm unsure if it is reliable if the time taken in the ajax code isn't guaranteed to finish before the wait is over)

Comment: The name of this technique is escaping me at the moment but here's the gist: https://jsfiddle.net/ozbgq57t/ (after the user changes the amount, only make the request after a certain time has passed; if the user changes the amount again before the timer expired, reset it)

Comment: The term is : debounce.  The "wait a bit" refers to the fact that you don't fire the *first* ajax request until after the timeout

Comment: In general, to solve the multiple requests issue, you need to write queue code. You need a way to keep track of all requests instead of let each change your app state independently, so a queue is usually the way to do this. Each new request gets added to the queue, and the .done() part checks if the queue is empty.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for, although I am still a little unclear if I have a timeout set to 2000, if the AJAX request took say 10 seconds would this cover it - is that what the reset of the timeout is doing? Looking at the network tab in Chrome it appears the AJAX request are then stacked one by one so it appears to - am I correct?